# Moving player towards clicked point in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D point-and-click game where i want the player to move towards clicked objects. This is my code for moving the player towards a door:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveOnClick : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject door;
public GameObject player;
public float speed;
public Vector3 target;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector3.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null) {
            player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that the player only moves one pixel per click. I want the player to move all the way to the door if the door is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector3.zero);  
    target = hit.transform.position;  
    }

    if (hit.collider != null) {
        player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```